# How to recognize a 408 HTTP-Statuscode?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, http-status-codes

I'm developing a firefox addon which performs actions if a statuscode is a 4xx or 5xx error. 
It works quite well as it is now, but it doesn't take actions if the error code is a 408.
 Firefox gives me an error but the error never reaches my extension.

My httpobserver looks like this:

```
observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData)
{       
    if (aTopic == 'http-on-examine-response') 
    {
        httpstatus = aSubject.responseStatus.toString();
        if(httpstatus.substr(0,1) in {4:1,5:1})
        {
          ...
```

I also tried to put an alert box after the httpstatus is set (right before the if) it alerts all codes it gets except for the 408 error.

Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you mean is most likely not "408 Timed Out" HTTP response (that would happen e.g. if a proxy server cannot reach the server) but `NS_ERROR_NET_TIMEOUT` - an error generated by Gecko if it cannot reach the server. `http-on-examine-response` notification is only triggered if a response from server is received, for `NS_ERROR_NET_TIMEOUT` this is not the case.

Unfortunately, listening to such errors isn't possible by means of observers. You can use a [progress listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Listening_to_events_on_all_tabs), whenever a load stops its `onStateChange` method will be called with `aStateFlags` including `LOAD_STOP` flag and `aStatus` being the channel status (`NS_ERROR_NET_TIMEOUT` in this case).

Comment: I do mean the error code 408, I developed a servlet which sends error codes to my client (for testing purposes). Your solution doesn't work for me, maybe I did it wrong? I tried the following `aStatus == 0x804B000E` `aStatus == "NS_ERROR_NET_TIMEOUT"` and `aStatus == "0x804B000E"` but neither of them work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Termi: `aStatus == Components.results.NS_ERROR_NET_TIMEOUT` but other than that I cannot really help much without seeing any code.

Comment: It does work now, thanks for your help! I alerted aStatus and NS_ERROR_NET_TIMEOUT and found out that if the error is a 408 the NS_ERROR_NET_TIMEOUT was 6 points below aStatus so I just added 6 and it works great now.

Comment: @Termi: "6 points above" would be NS_ERROR_NET_RESET - "Connection reset by peer". Sounds like your servlet isn't working correctly. See [nsNetError.h](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/public/nsNetError.h) for the full list of network errors.

Comment: As long as it works like it is I don't have a problem... I may come back here if errors occure during the tests, but thanks though.